How do I get the PTS of a video stream from the VLC plugin for Unity?
I'm working on a Unity project using the VLC plugin to display a live streaming, and I want access to the PTS for each frame to synchronize other things happening in my scene.
I've been looking closely at the libraries and forums, but unfortunately can't figure out how to access it. Neither the Media class nor the LibVLC class provide access to the streamed data (afaik). Maybe this is not possible at all?
Thank you in advance!

This is not supported by LibVLC AFAIK. You should probably be looking at FFmpeg directly.
